# Hair shedding from upper body while lower still have long hair

Tags: cats, health, hairloss

I have a male kitten, approx 9-10 months old. It is suffering from hair loss. I think it may be due to environmental allergies. Or is it due to something else?

It was shifted to my friend's house for approx 2 weeks and when I got it back, it was healthy with good coat and long hair. But after few days it started losing hair.

I visited vet but I don't think there are any good vets in my city. My vet always suggests me to change cat food brand whenever I pay a visit. Cat's diet was same when it was at my friend's place.

Currently we are feeding him "Josera kitten food". Before that we were feeding him "Royal Canin Kitten food".

What could be the cause? It has short hair from upper side and longer hair below his body. I don't trust any vet in my city. They are here just to make money.

Need advice. Thanks.

Comment: Is your cat licking herself too much? If not I will provide a different answer.

Comment: no not too much,

Comment: he is 9 months old, not neutered yet, no other pet in house

Comment: Search google images for "cat ringworm infection" and see whether your cat has similar condition. If not I will provide a different answer.

Comment: i googled it, no, my cat does not have "ringworm infection"

Comment: Is your cat purebred cat like Himalayan or Bengal cat?

Comment: it is a mix breed, turkish angora and persian mix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74705/discussion-between-sonevol-and-daniyal-javaid).

Answer (score 4):

The options of treatment in this case is not only limited but also expensive.

If it is hereditary then although there is no treatment, rest assured that your cat is fine. You may want to check with the pet shop for this information.

Otherwise as per information provided by you in your comments, your cat's condition is **serious**.

After ruling out other possible reasons as per information provided by you in your comments, your cat most probably has hyperthyroidism. However other diseases like diabetes, cancer and kidney failure may also be the reasons.

However it is rare condition for a 9 month old cat as these diseases mostly occur in older cats.

For diabetes diagnosis urine analysis, complete blood count and serum biochemistry profile is required.

Urine analysis, blood tests and clinical signs are used to diagnose kidney failure.

Blood tests, faeces test, radiography, ultrasonography and endoscope is used to diagnose intestinal cancer.

Usually these three conditions are first ruled out before testing for hyper thyroidism is done.

Enlarged thyroid gland in neck area is examined for physically. Tests like blood chemistry panel and analysis of thyroid hormone levels is done.

Treatment includes one or a combination of medicines, radioactive iodine therapy, surgery and dietary therapy.

**NOTE:** I AM NOT A VET

See a better vet asap. Time is crucial now.

Comment: does "hyperthyroidism" also lead to loud yowling ? because our cat has very loud voice and yowls most of the time

Comment: I don't think the two are linked

Comment: a 9 month old cat is an adult cat and is not only able to produce offspring but eager to do so too.you better get him nutered when you take him to the vet and get him vaccsinated at the same time.@DaniyalJavaid